# CRTP interface: different return types in implementation

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, return-type, crtp

**Note:**
In the explanation and my example, I'm using the `eigen` library. However, my question can probably be generalised and understood by people not familiar with that library, e.g. by replacing the `ConstColXpr` with `std::string_view` and the `Vector` with a `std::string`.

**Question:**
I want to create an interface using CRTP, with two classes inheriting from it which differ in the following way when callling certain member functions:

- The first class returns a view of a data member (an `Eigen::Matrix<...>::ConstColXpr`)
- The second class does not have this data member. Instead, the appropriate values are calculated when the function is called and then returned (as an `Eigen::Vector<...>`)

Both return types have the same dimensions (e.g. a 2x1 column vector) and the same interface, i.e. can be interacted with in the exact same way. That's why I believe it is reasonable to define the function as part of the interface.
However, **I don't know how to properly define/restrict the return type in the base class/interface**. `auto` compiles and executes fine, but doesn't tell the user anything about what to expect.

**Is it possible to define the interface in a clearer way?** I tried using `std::invoke_result` with the implementation function, but then I'd have to include the inheriting types before the interface, which is quite backwards. And it's not much better than `auto`, as the actual type still has to be looked up in the implementation.

A nice answer would be a common `Eigen` type, where the dimensions are clear. However, I don't want calls to the interface function to require template parameters (which I'd have to do with `Eigen::MatrixBase`), because there's already code depending on the interface.
Another nice answer would be some construct that allows two different return types, but without having to know the full derived type. But all answers and also other feedback are welcome!

Here's the code illustrating the issue:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    auto myFunc(int) const;

protected:
    Base();
};

template<typename T>
Base<T>::Base() {
    /* make sure the function is actually implemented, otherwise generate a
     * useful error message */
    static_assert( std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::myFuncImp)> );
}

template<typename T>
auto Base<T>::myFunc(int i) const {
    return static_cast<const T&>(*this).myFuncImp(i);
}


using Matrix2Xd = Eigen::Matrix<double,2,Eigen::Dynamic>;

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>
{
private:
    Matrix2Xd m_data;

public:
    Derived1( Matrix2Xd&& );

private:    
    auto myFuncImp(int) const -> Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr;
    friend Base;
};

Derived1::Derived1( Matrix2Xd&& data ) :
    m_data {data}
{}

auto Derived1::myFuncImp(int i) const -> Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr {
    return m_data.col(i);
}


class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2>
{
private:
    auto myFuncImp(int) const -> Eigen::Vector2d;
    friend Base;
};

auto Derived2::myFuncImp(int i) const -> Eigen::Vector2d {
    return Eigen::Vector2d { 2*i, 3*i };
}

int main(){
    Matrix2Xd m (2, 3);
    m <<
        0, 2, 4,
        1, 3, 5;

    Derived1 d1 { std::move(m) };

    std::cout << "d1: " << d1.myFunc(2).transpose() << "\n";

    Derived2 d2;

    std::cout << "d2: " << d2.myFunc(2).transpose() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, this prints

```
d1: 4 5
d2: 4 6
```

Comment: Could you do something stupid like returning a type that inherits from `ConstColXpr`, but may optionally contain a `Vector` that the `ConstColXpr` would then reference? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c8e0d58dd204d2f

Comment: I would actually just keep using a placeholder type (though `decltype(auto)` might be better), and document in comments and anywhere else appropriate the requirements for the type returned by `T::myFuncImp`, which are also the guarantees of the type returned by `Base<T>::myFunc`. This allows for some new derived class later to use some entirely new type, as long as it has the appropriate interface.

Comment: `Eigen::ConstColExpr` and `Eigen::Vector2d` don't have a common base class which expresses its dimension. You could statically assert that the `RowAtCompileTime` of your return type is 2 (and Cols==1). But also, returning `Vector2d` may even be more efficient than returning a reference to a column (at least on x86-64 a `Vector2d` is just passed via the `xmm0` register)

Comment: @chtz Right! Asserting the row and column count is a good idea, I was playing around with those values anyway, but somehow didn't make the connection. About the performance: yeah, I'll definitely have to test that. I have other instances where a four-row vector is returned, not sure at how many values the breakeven point lies. What does xmm0 do? Is that vector extension territory already?

Comment: `xmm0` is the first SSE register (it can hold either two doubles, or four floats, or four ints, or 8 shorts, etc)

Comment: Could you explain the bigger picture of why you want CRTP here? Does `Base` actually perform common work other than calling `myFuncImpl`?

Comment: @rustyx: Do you mean "why CRTP instead of 'normal' inheritance"?

Comment: @aschepler Why would ```decltype(auto)``` be better?

Comment: For example, if some derived class has `myFuncImpl` return type `const Thing&`, then `decltype(auto)` will have `myFunc` also return type `const Thing&`, but just `auto` will have `myFunc` return type `Thing`, forcing a copy.

Comment: @aschepler: omg, I would not have thought that. Quite counterintuitive! Where can I read up on that? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto covers it. Basically `decltype(auto)` follows the same rules as `decltype(`expression`)`, and any other placeholder type finds a type for `auto` using the same rules as template argument deduction, meaning `auto` by itself acts like deducing a function parameter type `T` for `f(T)`, `auto&` acts like the parameter in `f(T&)`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Adding another answer, because both answers are valid, and independent.

A different way is to define a traits class. The advantage over the previous answer is, that any code that wants to use an object of type `Base` doesn't have to have a multitude of template parameters. Multiple template parameters kind of implies that they can be mixed and matched, but the situation here is more about one template type logically implicating which types are supposed to be used.

First, an empty traits class is defined:

```
template<typename T>
class BaseTraits {};
```

This is the full definition, not a forward declaration. Then, it has to be specialised for each type derived from `Base`:

```
class Derived1; // forward declaration for the traits class

template<>
class BaseTraits<Derived1>
{
public:
    using VectorType = Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr;
};
```

and

```
class Derived2;

template<>
class BaseTraits<Derived2>
{
public:
    using VectorType = Eigen::Vector2d;
};
```

Now, `Base` can use the `VectorType` with a typealias:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    using VectorType = typename BaseTraits<T>::VectorType;

    auto myFunc(int) const -> VectorType; /* note the speaking return type */

protected:
    Base();
};
```

with the effect that it's now clear what `myFunc` is supposed to return - at least as clear as the naming of the traits ;)

Here's the full code:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


template<typename T>
class BaseTraits {};

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    using VectorType = typename BaseTraits<T>::VectorType;
    auto myFunc(int) const -> VectorType;

protected:
    Base();
};

template<typename T>
Base<T>::Base() {
    /* make sure the function is actually implemented, otherwise generate a
     * useful error message */
    static_assert( std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::myFuncImp)> );
}

template<typename T>
auto Base<T>::myFunc(int i) const -> VectorType {
    return static_cast<const T&>(*this).myFuncImp(i);
}


using Matrix2Xd = Eigen::Matrix<double,2,Eigen::Dynamic>;

class Derived1;

template<>
class BaseTraits<Derived1>
{
public:
    using VectorType = Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr;
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>
{
private:
    Matrix2Xd m_data;

public:
    Derived1( Matrix2Xd&& );

private:    
    auto myFuncImp(int) const -> Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr;
    friend Base;
};

Derived1::Derived1( Matrix2Xd&& data ) :
    m_data {data}
{}

auto Derived1::myFuncImp(int i) const -> Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr {
    return m_data.col(i);
}

class Derived2;

template<>
class BaseTraits<Derived2>
{
public:
    using VectorType = Eigen::Vector2d;
};

class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2>
{
private:
    auto myFuncImp(int) const -> Eigen::Vector2d;
    friend Base;
};

auto Derived2::myFuncImp(int i) const -> Eigen::Vector2d {
    return Eigen::Vector2d { 2*i, 3*i };
}

int main(){
    Matrix2Xd m (2, 3);
    m <<
        0, 2, 4,
        1, 3, 5;

    Derived1 d1 { std::move(m) };

    std::cout << "d1: " << d1.myFunc(2).transpose() << "\n";

    Derived2 d2;

    std::cout << "d2: " << d2.myFunc(2).transpose() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a reasonably readable solution. Feedback is still welcome.
I just defined another template parameter, a `bool`, which tells whether the derived class holds data, and defined the return type using `std::conditional` and that `bool`:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


using Matrix2Xd = Eigen::Matrix<double,2,Eigen::Dynamic>;
using Eigen::Vector2d;


template<typename T, bool hasData>
class Base
{
public:
    auto myFunc(int) const ->
        std::conditional_t<hasData, Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr, Vector2d>;

protected:
    Base();
};

template<typename T, bool hasData>
Base<T, hasData>::Base() {
    static_assert( std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::myFuncImp)> );
}

template<typename T, bool hasData>
auto Base<T, hasData>::myFunc(int i) const ->
std::conditional_t<hasData, Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr, Vector2d> {
    return static_cast<const T&>(*this).myFuncImp(i);
}



class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1, true>
{
private:
    Matrix2Xd m_data;

public:
    Derived1( Matrix2Xd&& );

private:    
    auto myFuncImp(int) const -> Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr;
    friend Base;
};

Derived1::Derived1( Matrix2Xd&& data ) :
    m_data {data}
{}

auto Derived1::myFuncImp(int i) const -> Matrix2Xd::ConstColXpr {
    return m_data.col(i);
}


class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2, false>
{
private:
    auto myFuncImp(int) const -> Eigen::Vector2d;
    friend Base;
};

auto Derived2::myFuncImp(int i) const -> Eigen::Vector2d {
    return Eigen::Vector2d { 2*i, 3*i };
}

int main(){
    Matrix2Xd m (2, 3);
    m <<
        0, 2, 4,
        1, 3, 5;

    Derived1 d1 { std::move(m) };

    std::cout << "d1: " << d1.myFunc(2).transpose() << "\n";

    Derived2 d2;

    std::cout << "d2: " << d2.myFunc(2).transpose() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and executes fine. Bit more verbose, but at least shows the intent clearly.

Other answers are still welcome.

Comment: Not saying this is necessarily off-topic on SO, but you might have a better chance of getting feedback on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)